# getting webapp2 session id

Tags: sessionid, webapp2

How to get a session id in webapp2?

It doesn't seem to be documented anywhere and it wasn't trivial to me.

I have found some solution, which I present in the answer to this question, but maybe somebody will find simpler or better one.
Anyway I think that this can be useful to somebody

Answer (score 2):

My solution looks like this:

```
import webapp2
from webapp2_extras import sessions

class Test(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        session_store = sessions.get_store(request=self.request)
        cookie_name = session_store.config['cookie_name']
        session_id = self.request.cookies[cookie_name]
        self.response.out.write('<html><body>')
        self.response.out.write('Session id: %s' % session_id)
        self.response.out.write("</body></html>")
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you can't get the session id, until you refresh the page. You should make an authenticate page to create the session. Also you should define a base handler that extends the dispatch() method to start the session store and save all sessions at the end of a request. Read the [documentation](http://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/webapp2_extras/sessions.html?highlight=Sessions) See an example:

```
class Main(main.BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        if not self.session.get('user'):
            self.redirect("/authenticate",abort=True)
        session = self.request.cookies("session")
        #more stuff........

class Authenticate(main.BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        if self.session.get('user'):
            self.redirect("/")
    else:
        self.render("authenticate.htm")

    def post(self):
        if self.session.get('user'):
            self.redirect("/",abort=True)

        post_param = {"username":self.request.get("username"),
                     "password":self.request.get("password")}

        if not post_param["password"] or not post_param["username"]:
            redirect("/authenticate") 

        mySql = dbLib.MySqlLib()
        try:
            mySql.query("SELECT password FROM users where username=%s", post_param["username"],))
            dbPassword = mySql.dbCur.fetchone()[0]
        except dbLib.ProgrmmgError as error:
            self.render("authenticate.htm",username = post_param["username"],
                                          errorMessage = "Password and/or Username\
        else:                                                  invalid")
            if bcrypt.hashpw(post_param["password"],dbPassword) == dbPassword:
                self.session['user'] = "root"
                self.redirect("/")
            else:
                self.render("authenticate.htm",username = post_param["username"],
                                               errorMessage = "Password and/or Username\
        mySql.close()

app = main.webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', Main),
                                    ("/authenticate",Authenticate),
                                    (".*",main.Error_404)],
                                     debug=True)
```

Comment: You are absolutely right. I just didn't mention things which are in documentation. I focused on things which aren't there and required looking into the source code